# How encrypt SQLite database with FireDAC?

Tags: sqlite, delphi

I'm create SQLite databse with DB Browser for SQLite (non encrypted) and open with FireDAC in delphi.(Can retrive data Eg. Select * from abc).

How encrypt this SQLite database with FireDAC? When enter username, password and encrypt get message  "Cipher DB is not encrypdet"

Note:

When create SQLite database from Delphi FireDac I can use encryption!

Comment: I'm afraid your q is not at all clear.  Are you asking how to use FireDAC to open a Sqlite database which has been created, with encryption using the D Browser at https://sqlitebrowser.org/, using version 3.11.2 or later?  If not, what exactly are you asking

Comment: @MartynA I open nonecrypted  db with firedac, how this db encrypt with firedac?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To encrypt a database, use a TFDSQLiteSecurity Component.  You'll also need a TFDSQLitePhysSQLiteDriverLink component to go along with it.

If a database is unencrypted, then its password is ''.  So use '' as the OldPassword and create the new password in that case.  Passwords are formatted as algorithm:PassPhrase.  See documentation on the choices, I use aes-256.  Also, the database needs to be closed when you do this.

```
...
//Change password
FDSQLiteSecurity1.Password := OldPassword;
FDSQLiteSecurity1.ToPassword := NewPassword;  // example: 'aes-256:mypassword123'
FDSQLiteSecurity1.ChangePassword;
...
//Remove Password
FDSQLiteSecurity1.Password := OldPassword;
FDSQLiteSecurity1.ToPassword := '';
FDSQLiteSecurity1.RemovePassword;
...
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [Documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Using_SQLite_with_FireDAC#SQLite_Encrypted_Database)

> **SQLite Encrypted Database**
>
> **Approach**
>
> One of the distinctive SQLite
> features is the high-speed strong database encryption. It allows you
> to make database file content confidential and enforce integrity
> control on the database file.  The encrypted database format is not
> compatible with other similar SQLite encryption extensions. **This means
> that you cannot use an encrypted database, encrypted with non-FireDAC
> libraries.** If you need to do this, then you have to decrypt a database
> with an original tool and encrypt it with FireDAC.

Comment: Tnx for answer, but my question is how encrypt non encrypted database with firedac?

Comment: @Pointer I do not think it is a Firedac or Delphi problem I think it is the version of the SQLite library used to create the db file.

Comment: @NasreddineGalfout Nope, you can do so by `TFDSQLiteSecurity` component from the `FireDAC Services` tab. Make sure also to use `TFDSQLiteValidate` to validate your db file, and also make sure to back up the db file using a `TFDSQLiteBackup` component before encrypting your db.

Comment: @Sami What are you talking about. This is a quote from the documentation on the product maker's website. What you said is true but not in this context.

Comment: The OP asking on _"How to encrypt an unencrypted SQLite database"_, it's not about if he can encrypt an already encrypted db by another tool. :)

Answer (score 1):

Recent Delphi versions come with an example project for working with encryption on Sqlite databases, see this [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Tokyo/en/FireDAC.SQLite_Encryption_Sample).  I have not used this myself, btw.

It includes this section

```
Encrypt DB
    Encrypt: Encrypts the database according to the Encryption mode and the password provided.

The sampe uses TFDSQLiteSecurity.SetPassword to encrypt the database with the password provided.

The database password is the combination of <encryption algorythm>:<password>.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced several challenges when first time tried to encrypt SQLite database for use with Embarcadero FireDAC.  Also all information is published by Embarcadero question pops up again and again on different forums. My case was solved based on community support, but when time has permitted simple Delphi application was assembled and available on Sourceforge. Hope it will make encryption/decryption slightly easier particularly for the newbie 
https://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlite-sequrity-for-delphi/